# How to select absolute link if two links are having same text in them?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am having two link

1. Engagement Rings
2. Rings

The above links are check box under dropdown menu

how can i select Rings using selenium xpath using `text()` method

Below is what i tried, but it is selecting "Engagement Ring"

```
//li//a[contains(text(),'Rings')]
```

but it is selecting Engament Ring as it appears before Rings in menu

My Code:

```
//Select Sub-Menu item from collection dropdown     
WebElement selectSub = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='popover fade right in']//div[2]//li//a[contains(text(),'Rings')]"));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply.. but unfortunately its not working.

Comment: what exactly *not working*? Share error logs

Comment: @Andersson There is no any error log. Can you please provide me your email address. I will send you my code and application screenshot for better explanation

Comment: You can edit your question with code sample and image

Comment: does this `WebElement selectSub = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Rings"));` select correct item?

Comment: @Andersson Thanks.. Its working :)

Comment: Welcome. You can accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243269/how-to-select-absolute-link-if-two-links-are-having-same-text-in-them/44243926#44243926) which contains the same solution :)

Answer (score 3):

This is selecting `Engagement Rings` because you are using `contains()` method

it will locate the element which contains match text So your first checkbox has "Rings" text

Just change your xpath to :

```
//li//a[text()='Rings']
```

OR

```
//li//a[normalize-space()='Rings']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below xpath i hope it will work

```
//li//a[starts-with(text(),'Rings')]
```

Comment: This won't match `"Engagement Rings"`, but it might match something like `"Rings and Rolls"`...